# warning: offset of on non-standard-layout type 'DerivedClass'

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-layout

I need to get rid of this warning. As far as I understand, it appears because DerivedClass is not considered as Plain Old Data. I read cppreference about [POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) and [Standard Layout Type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) but I still do not understand why DerivedClass is not a POD. If I put members of BaseClass into DerivedClass and do not use inheritance - then everything is OK. I use C++11

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BaseClass
{
public:
    int a;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    int b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // warning: offset of on non-standard-layout type 'DerivedClass'
    int offset = offsetof(DerivedClass, b);

    cout << offset;
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your setup does not seem to match the definition of Standard layout. But maybe it's a case of the XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6):

These are the requirements for standard layout type:

> All non-static data members have the same access control
>
> Has no virtual functions or virtual base classes
>
> Has no non-static data members of reference type
>
> All non-static data members and base classes are themselves standard layout types

Until C++14:

> Either
>
> has no base classes with non-static data members, or
>
> has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members
>
> Has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member (see empty base optimization)

This part applies to this example:

```
has no base classes with non-static data members,
```

In your case you have a base class with non static data members. Removing `a`  removes the warning.

After C++14, there are similar constraints, you cannot have members in the two classes, only one:

> Has all non-static data members and bit-fields declared in the same class (either all in the derived or all in some base)